# The current identity does not have write access to 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\myapp\Temporary ASP.NET Files'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

After publishing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application to **Windows Azure websites**, I receive the following error message when attempting to load the site.  The site works as expected on my development server.

What steps can I take to rectify this issue?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The current identity (IIS APPPOOL\myapp) does not have write access to 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\myapp\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The current identity (IIS APPPOOL\myapp) does not have write access to 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\myapp\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): The current identity (IIS APPPOOL\myapp) does not have write access to 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\myapp\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.SetUpCodegenDirectory(CompilationSection compilationSection) +9899906
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +199

[HttpException (0x80004005): The current identity (IIS APPPOOL\myapp) does not have write access to 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\myapp\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9877804
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.19064
```

Comment: As a quick test, if you try creating a new web site and publishing the same bits to it, do you get the same error? If so, we'd need to identify what's different about your MVC app since normally they work fine. If not, then maybe something is busted with that site (does site restart help?).

Answer (score 2):

From the Azure management portal try performing a full **STOP** on the website, wait a minute and then **START**.

We were having this *exact* same issue and although a quick 'restart' had no effect (although I tried multiple times) I decided to take David Ebbo's suggestion a bit further and that worked for us.